# Wix: multiple instances removes previous instance

Tags: wix

I have created a `Product.wxs` file with `<InstanceTransforms>` to install multiple instances of my product. When I execute the msi with the `MSINEWINSTANCE=1` and `TRANSFORMS=":P1"` parameters the install process works just fine. Now when I want to install another instance using `TRANSFORMS=":P2"` the previous instance of `P1` gets uninstalled.

Is there a way to avoid that?
I have also followed the [Revisited: Mutliple Instance installations](https://sklyarenko.net/posts/revisited-multiple-instance-and-patches) guide by Yan Sklyarenko but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I've found the solution. Inside the required `<UpgradeVersion>` tag I added the `OnlyDetect="yes"` attribute which avoids the instances from being uninstalled.

Comment: Would that not fail all major upgrades?